# Regex in DataDog lambda forwarder

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, datadog

I am setting up the Datadog lambda forwarder to send logs from cloudwatch to DD.

[DD lambda](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/guide/forwarder/?tab=cloudformation)

The lambda is up and I can see logs in to DD.

I would like to remove from logs a token and other sensitive information that are stored in the cloudwatch logs.

according to the documentation I need to setup an env variable in the lambda

```
DD_SCRUBBING_RULE   = /"(?i)authorization(.*)()\"/gm
```

you can see my attempt setting up the regex

[here](https://regex101.com/r/IammX2/1)

or

```
\\\"authorization\\\":\\\"Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxx.ngfsngfsngfsnsfgnsgfngfsn._OEKIQbQG7cMpCpBWH-k8Ev3WRiX_NsPjq_zHaCt5nI\\\"
```

using

```
"(?i)authorization(.*)()"gm
```

where I try to scrub a token

looks like the regex is correct and I am able to grab.

and if I enable debug logs I can see that

```
[DEBUG] 2023-06-06T09:13:36.378Z DD_SCRUBBING_RULE: /"(?i)authorization(.*)()\"/gm
```

The scrubbing rule is been read, but nonetheless the log is sent to DD without removing this sensitive information

is there something wrong in my regex?

----- UPDATE

I wrote a Python script

```
import re

string = ',\\\"authorization\\\":\\\"Bearer xxxxxx.yyyyy.fff-dddd\\\",'

# Find the authorization value using regex
match = re.search(r'"authorization\\":\\"Bearer (.*?)\\",', string)

if match:
    authorization_value = match.group(1)
    print(authorization_value)
else:
    print("Authorization value not found.")
```

which gets what I want but if I copy and paste that regex into

[enter link description here](https://regex101.com/r/nlP271/1)

my regular expression does not match the subject string

Comment: `"`s and `gm` are not actually part of the pattern, so you cannot add these elements to a field that is passed as a pattern only. So, try `authorization(.*)` first (not sure you need an empty Group 2). Then, since the resulting pattern looks to be a JavaScript like regex, you you cannot use `(?i)` and you have to use something like `[aA][uU][tT][hH][oO][rR][iI][zZ][aA][tT][iI][oO][nN](.*)`.